# Generic interface problem

Tags: c#, .net, interface, application-design

I'd like to have one interface for all my grid related tasks.The tasks implement this interface:

```
public interface IDataForGrid<T>
{
    IGridResponse<T> GetList(IGridRequest request);
}
```

The T type is always a DTO class. I cant't create a common interface for this DTOs because they have nothing common.Just a dumb DTO with particular properties.

I'd like to use it like this :

```
public class Service1
{
    public IGridResponse CreateResponse(IGridRequest request)
    {

        ...
        IDataForGrid<T> aa;

        if(request == 1) aa = new CustomerGridData;
        if(request == 2) aa = new OrderGridData;

        var coll = aa.GetList();
    }
}

public class CustomerGridData : IDataForGrid<CustomerDTO>
{
   ...
}
```

The problem is I don't know what to put instead of the T.

Comment: There was an error in my post, it's fixed now

Comment: What are you going to do with `coll` ?

Comment: follow up question asked over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424287/is-having-an-empty-base-class-bad-design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe Im miss-understanding you, but couldnt you make a super class that all of your DTO's like `BaseDTO`

Then use it like so:

```
public class CustomerDTO : BaseDTO {}

IDataForGrid<BaseDTO> aa;

var coll = aa.GetList();
```

This way, your `coll` variable will be of type `IGridResponse<BaseDTO>` which all of your DTO object extend from.

That make sense?

Comment: Yes, you understood it well. But what to put in the base class ? The DTOs have nothing common.

Comment: you technically dont need anything in the base class, although having nothing in there sort of feel weird. But if thats the cost of getting your way in other more detailed areas of your code, then so be it. Chances are that in the future your DTO's will end up having something in common anyways, they usually do :)

Comment: will you not get a cast exceptions when casting? IDataForGrid<object> aa = new CustomerDataGrid();

Answer (score 3):

You can make the method generic as well so that T can be substituted as required:

```
public class Service1
{
  public IGridResponse<T> CreateResponse<T>(IGridRequest request)
  {
    ...
    IDataForGrid<T> aa;

    if(request == 1) cg = new CustomerGridData;
    if(request == 2) og = new OrderGridData;

    var coll = aa.GetList();
  }
}
```