# Is there a base class from which all members of the C++ standard library derive?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, polymorphism, base-class

C++/CLI has a System::Object class to serve this purpose, but I can't seem to find one in the standard library. Basically I'm writing a set of classes, and I would like the base class to store a vector of `std::string`in a `content` property, but derived classes might need to store a vector of something else (perhaps even one of my own classes). It might seem like an odd goal, but I'm writing a some file access classes to let me more easily manipulate files of different formats. The base `File` class will store each line in a string, as part of the vector - but a class for JSON, for instance, might need to store JS-Style collections/objects, etc.

The only way I could think to do this is to have the `content` property a vector of objects (or some other universal base class - I can derive any custom classes from it for polymorphism's sake too) and then cast it back into whatever type is necessary depending on the type of child object that is being used. I soon discovered that I couldn't find any mention of `std::object` (or similar) anywhere.

This example should demonstrate what I'm trying to do:

```
class File {
protected:
    std::vector<std::object> _content;

public:
    //Contructors/methods/etc.

    std::string getItemAt(size_t index) {
        return static_cast<std::string>(this->_content[index]);
    }

    void setItemAt(size_t index, std::string value) {
        this->_content[index] = static_cast<std::object>(value);
    }
};

class JSONFile: File {
public:
    //Constructors/methods/etc.

    SomeObject getItemAt(size_t index) {
        return static_cast<SomeObject>(this->_content[index]);
    }

    void setItemAt(size_t index, SomeObject value) {
        this->_content[index] = static_cast<std::object>(value);
    }
};
```

Note that this example assumes that `std::object` exists, and that `SomeObject` would be whatever is used to handle the JSON (again, for example - this could be anything) data. `SomeObject` would obviously derive from `std::object`.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, *or* if I'm going completely the wrong way about this, any feedback as to how I could do it so that the `std::object` thing isn't necessary would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I dont understand why you are looking for something like `std::object`. If you need a base class for your own classes, just write one

Comment: Check out `boost::any`

Comment: See [Why is base-for-all-objects discouraged in C++](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/273305/165156)

Comment: @tobi303 actually I need to morph to and from std::string _as well_ as my own classes - hence my dilemma

Comment: @BradSullivan sorry, I still dont see the problem. Just write classes (inheriting from your base class) that contain a `std::string` or `std::whatever` or `XYZ::My_own_class`

Comment: @tobi303 To be perfectly honest I never thought of that! Thanks :) haha

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

Because C++ is all about "you only pay for what you use".

What would the interface of `std::object` look like? If there were any member functions, those would have to be `virtual` to be of any use, resulting in a runtime cost because of dynamic dispatch.

If the hypothetical `std::object` was an empty class, what could you do with a `std::object` reference? Not much, since it wouldn't have any member functions to call. Why make everything derive from a single base when they have nothing in common.

---

If you ***really*** need a base for all of your classes, you can always write one. But note that doing so [might not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12923294/3425536) be [a good](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65511/can-you-have-empty-abstract-classes) [design decision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2424287/3425536).

Comment: That's a fair point. Do you know why it is that C++/CLI implements one?

Comment: I like this thought process. I would like to expand that you also want to think about what the storage requirements of the hypothetical std::object would be to store it in a contiguous array.

Comment: @BradSullivan: To implement [Common Type System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Type_System) :)  You may find more information at [What's So Common About the Common Type System](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/commontypesystemcts/article.php/c4631/Whats-So-Common-About-the-Common-Type-System-CTS.htm)

Comment: @Landon Being an abstract class (supposedly), you could only store pointers to it in the array.

Comment: @Landon ahh okay so there's no need for a common type system in standard C++ because it doesn't need to be compatible with other languages. Makes sense :)

Comment: @zenith Yes, which is less than ideal because your array objects are possibly all over memory.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a base class from which all members of the C++ standard library derive?

The short answer is "No."
The long answer is "Definitely not."

An answer that provides more details can be seen at a related SO site: [Why is base-for-all-objects discouraged in C++](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/273305/why-is-base-for-all-objects-discouraged-in-c).

Comment: Could you elaborate in an "extremely long answer"? It is more useful for me browsing answers to see the "Why not" rather than the absolute answer.

Answer (score 2):

When I see you define

```
std::vector<std::object> _content;
```

it tells me that  your goal is to rather do generic programming with templates than object oriented programming with inheritance. This is the same style of std::vector and co., so it shouldn't look too unfamiliar.

Your code could be:

```
template <typename FileObject>
class File {
public:
    std::vector<FileObject> _content;

public:
    //Constructors/methods/etc.

    FileObject getItemAt(size_t index) {
        return this->_content[index];
    }

    void setItemAt(size_t index, std::string value) {
        this->_content[index] = FileObject(value);
    }
};
```

then use it as

```
json_files = File<JSONObject>();
json_files.setItemAt(1, "{}");
```

or if you have special operations you want to perform on your json object list, the function can take an explicit `File<JSONObject>` parameter. It's also possible to inherit from `File<JSONObject>`, but mixing and matching OO/Generic is discouraged.

Now, closer to your title question: you can't easily store different File types in the same vector, but think about how you would implement that. What are the storage requirements for `File<int>`? For `File<double>`? This is a core spot where your OO/inheritance solution will become ungainly and using generic programming makes it impossible to *try*, which is good.

Comment: Whoops, this comment doesn't actually answer your question about core base class, but rather cutting to the core issue with your interface.

Comment: That's actually great - thanks! I did ask for suggestions too so this answer is definitely a valid one.

Comment: Thank you. I wonder why it was flooded with downvotes after posting.

Comment: This doesn't quite have the same functionality as a common base class; the template parameter must be known at compile-time.

Comment: In his use case, he already knew the type at compile time by virtue of wanting a JSONFile. Generally though, you are correct.

Comment: @BradSullivan If you don't mind, check out the last few paragraphs of my answer again. I didn't check that `File<Double>` was rendered correctly and it might have been extra confusing.

Comment: @Landon I think I get what you mean, though ideally I don't think I would need a File<int> etc. because the _contents property is only storing sections of the file - in the base File class, it happens to be broken up by lines but other derivatives of that class might break it up differently. Were I to store a File of ints I would likely extract them as strings anyway and convert them only when necessary.

Comment: Right, those were just hypothetical cases as types you might be able to more easily reason about storage requirements.